# Mysql Update Parent Category Id using parent name

Tags: php, mysql

I have MYSQL table like this

```
id     category_name                parent_name            parent_id
1      Animals & Pet Supplies       NULL                       0
2      Live Animals                 Animals & Pet Supplies     0
3      Pet Supplies                 Animals & Pet Supplies     0
4      Bird Supplies                Pet Supplies               0
5      Bird Cage Accessories        Bird Supplies              0
```

Now I want to update parent_id with id of parent_name in category_name
like below

```
id     category_name                parent_name            parent_id
1      Animals & Pet Supplies       NULL                       0
2      Live Animals                 Animals & Pet Supplies     1
3      Pet Supplies                 Animals & Pet Supplies     1
4      Bird Supplies                Pet Supplies               3
5      Bird Cage Accessories        Bird Supplies              4
```

by default the value of parent id is 0, it should be 0 if parent_name=NULL other wise it should be updated with corresponding id of category_name.

Comment: Sounds good. Why don't you do it? Do you have any question regarding this? But if you do, you should also think about removing `parent_name` afterwards, because it won't be normalized db structure afterwards (parent_name will be redundant, because you can find out the parent's name by the parent_id's name)

Comment: thank you Alexander , I need update query to update parent id , now all parent_id's are 0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be something like this:

```
UPDATE my_table SET parent_id=
   (SELECT id FROM my_table t1 WHERE t1.name=my_table.parent_name)
   WHERE parent_name IS NOT NULL;
```

Although mysql may refuse nested SELECT query for the same table, in which case you might need to create a new temporary table like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_table_temp AS SELECT * FROM my_table;
UPDATE my_table SET parent_id=
   (SELECT id FROM my_table t1 WHERE t1.name=my_table.parent_name)
   WHERE parent_name IS NOT NULL;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE my_table_temp;
```

Comment: Don't forget the `where parent_name IS NOT NULL` statement.

Comment: Good point - I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using `update with left join`

```
update 
table_name t1 
left join table_name t2 on t1.parent_name = t2.category_name
set t1.parent_id = coalesce(t2.id,0) ;
```

Comment: my query is "update 
master_categories t1 
left join master_categories t2 on t1.parent_name = t2.category_name
set t1.parent_id = t2.id " it is showing error  Unknown column 't2.id' in 'field list'

Comment: Use `set t1.parent_id = coalesce(t2.id,0) ;` so that the non matching data remains as `0` for `parent_id` instead of `null`